# Changing default queue to other Broadcasting event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to change default queue to another queue of broadcasting event but not work.

I'm tried following instruction from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#broadcast-queue). Add `public $broadcastQueue = 'exports';` but its still running on default queue.

I'm using laravel 5.8. Here is my code.

My controller:

```php
$paramRequest = $request->input();
dispatch(new ProcessExportExcel($paramRequest))->onQueue('exports');
return response()->json('job dispatched to default queue');
```

My job:

```php
class ProcessExportExcel implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $request;

    public $tries = 3;

    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $condition = $this->request;
        // export excel process...
        event(new ExportNotificationEvent($responeData));
    }
}
```

My event:

```php
class ExportNotificationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public $broadcastQueue = 'exports';

    public function broadcastQueue()
    {
        return 'exports';
    }

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('excel-channel.' . $this->data['userId']);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'excel-event';
    }
}
```

I'm solved my problem by using ShouldBroadcastNow instead of ShouldBroadcast.

Comment: This looks fine to me. Are you sure the updated code is used when you dispatch the job or fire the event? In other words, did you restart your queue workers, so they have the updated code to execute?

Comment: Yes. I did restart my worker. But nothing changes.
My solution is change ShouldBroadcast to ShouldBroadcastNow.

Comment: This isn't really a solution, although it doesn't hurt too much in your situation as the triggering task is already executed in the background. I'm pretty sure you have an issue with the queue workers not picking up the new code. Did you check that after terminating the queue workers, they are actually gone (`ps aux | grep queue` or `ps aux | grep horizon` in case you use horizon)?